# sql case statement error

Tags: sql

I have a case statement, however; I'm getting two erros. I can't seem to find the answer to the fix the errors.

```
SELECT #TMP.webid_Val = CASE #TMP.webid 
when 'NULL' then 'NOT COMPLIANT'
else 'COMPLIANT'
end
FROM #TMP
```

****Incorrect syntax near FROM. Expecting CONVERSATION**

**Incorrect syntax near =****

`#TMP` is the temporary table. 
webid is the value to be looked at for the condition
webid_val is the column who's value will be changed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Why** are you starting your table name with the character `'#'`?!

Comment: what do you mean "webid_val is the column who's value will be changed"? Are you trying to perform an UPDATE?

Comment: yes I am. I read that it's better to use the case statments then an update due to performance.

Comment: @MasterP if you are trying to perform an UPDATE then you need to use an UPDATE, you cannot use a CASE statement to update the data in a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The following answer assumes Sql Server)
You cannot do an update with a select statement.

If you are trying to return data to a client application or user, use

```
SELECT webid_Val = CASE 
    WHEN #TMP.webid IS NULL then 'NOT COMPLIANT'
    ELSE 'COMPLIANT'
END
FROM #TMP
```

or if you're trying to update data in the original temp table, use the following:

```
UPDATE #tmp SET 
webid_Val = CASE 
    WHEN #TMP.webid IS NULL then 'NOT COMPLIANT'
    ELSE 'COMPLIANT'
END
FROM #TMP
```

Answer (score 3):

It sure seems like you want to perform an `UPDATE` using a `CASE` statement the way you were will not `UPDATE` the data in the table

```
UPDATE #TMP
SET webid_Val = 
    (CASE when webid Is NULL
        then 'NOT COMPLIANT'
        else 'COMPLIANT'
        end)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your notes correctly, you are wanting to do an update statement, not a select statement. Also, null is not a string.

the below will execute the select statement if that's all you want.

```
select case #TMP.webid when null then 'NOT COMPLIANT'
        else 'COMPLIANT' end
from #TMP
```

if you want to update every row in the table:

```
update #TMP
set webid_Val = (case webid when null then 'NOT COMPLIANT'
            else 'COMPLIANT' end)
```